# What is implicit evidence in Scala? What is it good for?

Tags: scala, types, implicit

I see the term "implicit evidence" in many SOF and blog posts, related to runtime retention of type information. I searched the net but have not found any simple explanation what "implicit evidence" is.

This concept comes up, for example, [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html).

EDIT:

A comment to Travis' nice answer:

From [Predef.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Predef.scala):

```
  sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) 
      with Serializable

  private[this] final val singleton_<:< = 
      new <:<[Any,Any] { def apply(x: Any): Any = x }

  implicit def conforms[A]: A <:< A = singleton_<:<.asInstanceOf[A <:< A]
```

I don't see how the `unzip`'s "`asPair`" function parameter can be derived from `singleton_<:<.asInstanceOf[A <:< A]`. Could someone please comment on this?

Comment: +1, by the way—this could use some links but it's a perfectly reasonable question and I don't see why it's getting votes to close.

Comment: Perhaps because the original version was asking several related questions like : What is it precisely?

Why is it needed?

When is it used?

How is it created ?

Who creates it?

Where is it documented?

Comment: Suppose your list is of type `List[(Int, String)]`. For `unzip` you need an implicit `(Int, String) => (A, B)` for some `A` and `B`. Implicit search finds that `conforms` will produce a `(Int, String) <:< (Int, String)`, which is a subtype of `(Int, String) => (Int, String)`, and so it plugs that in.

Comment: For newcomers to Scala, it may be worth mentioning that `implicit` is a language keyword, whereas calling the parameter "evidence" is just a convention, and other names are often used - as you can see from the `asPair" example in the answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A good example in the standard library is the definition of `unzip` on e.g. a `List[A]`:

```
def unzip[A1, A2](implicit asPair: (A) ⇒ (A1, A2)): (List[A1], List[A2])
```

The goal is to allow the following to compile:

```
val (ks, vs) = List('a -> 1, 'b -> 2, 'c -> 3).unzip
```

But not this:

```
val (ks, vs) = List(1, 2, 3).unzip
```

This is accomplished via an implicit argument that *witnesses* that the type of the list can be viewed as a pair. In the example above this evidence is provided by [`Predef.conforms`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef%24), which for any type `A` will implicitly provide an instance of `A <:< A`, which is a subtype of `A => A`. The instance provided by `conforms` will of course just be the identity function.

If you look at [the definition of `unzip`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenericTraversableTemplate.scala#L83), you'll see how the evidence is used in this case:

```
def unzip[A1, A2](implicit asPair: A => (A1, A2)): (CC[A1], CC[A2]) = {
    val b1 = genericBuilder[A1]
    val b2 = genericBuilder[A2]
    for (xy <- sequential) {
      val (x, y) = asPair(xy)
      b1 += x
      b2 += y
    }
    (b1.result, b2.result)
  }
```

I.e., it's used to deconstruct the items in the sequence. Remember that this method is defined on any `List[A]`, so writing plain old `val (x, y) = xy` wouldn't compile.

Other applications of implicit evidence may have different goals (some [quite complex](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/09/learning-shapeless/)) and may use the implicit evidence in different ways (it's not necessarily just a function), but the basic pattern is generally going to be more or less the same as what you see with `unzip`.